# OnLongClickListener not working with achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine, onlongclicklistener

I am working with achartengine and I want to activate Action Mode in Action Bar when I Long-Click on the chart. But the OnLongClickListener is not working, I have searched everywhere I tried almost everything but I can't get it working and I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
mChartView.setLongClickable(true);
mChartView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Log.i("ClickListener", "CLICK");
            return false;
        }

});
```

But the event is never called, I think it is because the chart is scrollable but doesn't make sense. I tried whit OnClick and also doesn't work. The only one which is working is OnTouch but I can't get the behaviour of Long-Press.

**EDIT:**

Or maybe is any way of get the actual state of the touchscreen state, on this way, I can put a "timer" until it reaches for example 1000mS but only while the touchscreen is touched, because inside the onTouch event I can only know the state of the touchscreen when the event ocurred, no matter which is the current state.

Ok, here some code for a line chart:

```
private static XYSeries input1;
private static XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset;
private static XYSeriesRenderer renderer1;
private static XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer;
private static GraphicalView mChartView;

mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();

        mRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer1);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMax(10);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMax(10);
        mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.WHITE);
        mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
        mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);

        input1 = new XYSeries("Linea");

        mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        mDataset.addSeries(input1);

        renderer1.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        input1.add(4, 7);   
        input1.add(7, 3);   
        input1.add(8, 6);   
        input1.add(9, 2);

        mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer);
        setContentView(mChartView);

        mChartView.setLongClickable(true);
        mChartView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Click", "LONG CLICKED CHART");
                return false;
            }

        });
```

I am trying to do the Long-Click with onTouch because I realised that if I slide the graph it will be taked as Long-Click also, so I have to take a Long-Click BUT if I don't slide the graph.

Comment: do you also have an onTouchListener set on the same View? if so can you post the code for that as well?

Comment: No, I only have OnLongClickListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a runnable in conjunction with the onTouchListener() to get the same effect as onLongClick(). Something like this should do it:

```
boolean fingerStillDown = false;
final Runnable longClickRun = new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
       if(fingerStillDown){
           Log.i("CHARTS!", "LONGCLICK!");
       }
   }
 };
 mChartView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){
         if(me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
              fingerStillDown = true;
              //The system registers longclick at ~500ms.
              mChartView.postDelayed(longClickRun, 500);
         }

         if(me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
             fingerStillDown = false;
         }


         return false; //<-- I didn't test with true, but I suspect returning true
                       // would break the scrolling.
         }
  });
```

Comment: I created a new Activity whit a simple Line Chart and doesn't work :/

Comment: Hmm, can you post some working code that will create a line chart? I am unfamilar with aChartEngine and I am having trouble getting a line chart made right now. I think your best bet is to use a touchListener with a timer like you've stated in your Edit. If you post some working line chart code I can help you with implementing the touchListener correctly.

Comment: @Andres see my edited answer. Sorry I didn't get it posted last night. This method is working for me with the example code that you provided.

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly and I tweaked it a little to avoid Long-Press while I scroll the chart:) I didn't knwow about postDelayed()

Comment: Glad I could help. the Handler object has a postDelayed() method as well. Incase you ever need that functionality but don't have a View handy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to **return true** instead of false. That way the element was long pressed, so the evend has been handled.

```
mChartView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Log.i("ClickListener", "CLICK");
            return true;
        }

});
```

Comment: I think he would still be seeing the log statement if this were his problem.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7725994/828728), I think that might help. You can check an official sample [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java?r=367) too.